# Add multiple hyperlinks to multiple cells in worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Hie,

facing problems in adding multiple hyperlinks to multiple cells in sheet in one go.

[example given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmOjh.jpg)

column B contains the hyperlinks, having the name of the file common to column A

wants that if its dragged down it should change the hyperlink as per the source data.

Comment: You can use the `HYPERLINK` function and construct the hyperlink dynamically using a formula. Please note that superuser.com is not a "do my work for me" site. If you try and fail, tell us what you've tried and where you're stuck and we can try to help.

Comment: @ Atzmon- have tried it ,facing problems as the same file appears on clicking all of the cells in columns B, its not changing according to the respective cell reference in A column

Comment: What was the formula you were using?

Comment: used this formula - =HYPERLINK("C:\Users\sameer\Desktop\hyper/"&RC[-1]&".jpg")

Comment: it worked ...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the formula to generate the first link, in cell B1:

`=HYPERLINK("C:\Users\sameer\Desktop\hyper\" & A1 & ".jpg")`

You can drag down column B to generate the other links.

Comment: Consider marking this answer as the solution. Thanks.